# Alpha Zero queen promotion

Tags: neural-networks, chess, alphazero, deepmind

"The final 9 planes encode possible underpromotions for pawn moves or captures in two possible diagonals, to knight, bishop or rook  respectively.   Other  pawn  moves  or  captures  from  the  seventh  rank  are  promoted  to  a queen." 
Doesn't this mean that the network does not know that it can promote to a queen?

Answer (score 3):

It means that there is no explicit coding of action choices to promote to queen, it is the default assumption if the underpromotion actions are not taken.

The Alpha Zero chess implementation can represent promotion to queen by not selecting an underpromotion action, whilst moving a pawn so that it qualifies for promotion.